How to increase file upload limit to 100 mb using visualforce page in salesforce
Currently using apex:inputfile in vf page to upload image which have a hard limit of 10MB And my requirement is finding a workaround to increase the limit to 100MB.
Approach I am trying is created an lwc using  it is working fine on lightning tab but when I include the lwc inside my visualforce The UI is present it open the file select window but not showing the the upload progress window which have a done button the file upload succesfully only when we click on done button on progress window.
if it sound confusing below is the image of window we are missing This window wont appear when i try to upload from visualforce.
<apex:page Controller="LoginController" action="{!LoginTimeCheck}" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
 <apex:includeLightning />
<style>
    #SearchId {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-right: 0;
    }
    #serachbtnId {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    }
</style>

<div id="CaseForm" class="container">
    <h3 style='margin-left: 6.3rem;font-family: halcom !important;'>SUMMARY</h3><br/><br/>
    <apex:form id="theform">
        <div class="row">
            
            <div style='margin-left: 6.3rem'>
                <label>Attach File</label>
                <!--<apex:inputFile value="{!file}" id="fileupload" fileName="{!UploadedfileName}"/>-->
            <div id="fileUploaderContainer" />
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div style='margin-left: 6.3rem'>
            <apex:commandButton id="theButton" styleClass="registerbutton" value="Create" action="{!saveCaseRecord}" onclick="on();"  status="status"/>
            &nbsp;<input type="button" class="cancelbtn" value="Cancel" onclick = 'setTimeout(function() { location.reload() }, 1)'/>
        </div>
    </apex:form>
</div>

</apex:outputPanel>

<script>


 // Create and initialize the LWC component with the recordId from the controller
     document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        $Lightning.use('c:fileUploaderApp', function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent('c:fileUploader',
                { recordId: '{!theSelectedCaseId}' },
                'fileUploaderContainer',
                function(cmp) {
                    console.log('LWC Component added in VF page');
                }
            );
        });
    });

function on() {
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.theform.theButton}').value = 'Processing...';
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

</script> 
<footer id='footer'>
    <apex:include pageName="SiteFooter"></apex:include> 
</footer>

</apex:page>

You simply can't upload a file of 100MB in Apex. Instead, use apex:remoteObjects or the AJAX Proxy. Either of these should allow you to upload much larger files. Also, the suggestion about using the Chatter Rest API is a legitimate option if you want to upload files up to 2GB in size. In other words, there's lots of options to you, but Apex isn't the path forward.

Thanks for replying Actually  I made some progress and edited my question accordingly  currently I am Using Lightning-FIle-Upload in lwc and then using it inside my visualforce so is it possible to upload a large file by this manner
